# javascript как заменить у слове if else на более компактную запись?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, в коде есть условие:

```
if (typeof sbjs.get.current.typ !== "undefined") {
      var type_traffic = sbjs.get.current.typ;
    } else {
      var type_traffic = null;
    }
```

надо это условие заменить на более компактную запись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте конструкция ? :

```
 var type_traffic = (typeof sbjs.get.current.typ !== "undefined") ? sbjs.get.current.typ : null;
```

И никогда не объявляйте переменные внутри циклов/условий. В вашем случае нужно было объявить переменную до if.

```
var type_traffic;
if (typeof sbjs.get.current.typ !== "undefined") {
      type_traffic = sbjs.get.current.typ;
    } else {
      type_traffic = null;
    }
```

Comment: _И никогда не объявляйте переменные внутри циклов/условий_ почему же?

Comment: спасибо, сократил код на, десяток другой, строчек кода )))))

Comment: @Grundy, потому что объявления все равно баблятся, и может случиться взрыв мозга у того кто это не понимает

Comment: @ru_volt, это только если с помощью `var` объявлено

Comment: @ru_volt, да и правила довольно просты